# extrapolation of logarithmic graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, mathematica

I need to extrapolate the following graph.

Could someone help me with the formula for the logarithmic graph?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

1. read two points from the graph, for example `(1,200)` and `(1000,10)` (those are the points at the right and left border).
2. Calculate the log10 for each: `(0,2.301)`, `(3,1)`.
3. Use those two points to fit a line through - `y = ax+b` => `2.301 = 0a +b`; `1 = 3a +b` => the first one conveniently collapses to `b=2.301`, and using this in the second one gives `a=-1.301/3=-0.434`

So your line is `y = -0.434 x + 2.301`, and if you want it back in the base variables `log(p) = -0.434*log(t) + 2.301`